# Eclipse Unable to publish to WeSphere

Tags: eclipse, maven, wsdl, websphere-7, ibm-wdt

I have a mabven project structure as follow

project1
-- Main pom is here

project2
-- This is my EAR project

Project3
-- This is my JAX-WS client project

Project4
-- This is my EAR project

All of these are bundled together in a single EAR file. Maven build run successfully and ear also gets deployed to WebSphere(v7) from ADMIN console.

But When I am trying to publish it to WAS from eclipse(I have web sphere developer tools plugin installed in my Eclipse) it shows some weird error as follows..

javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'file:/C:/Workspaces/Project3/target/classes/META-INF/wsdl/'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That message typically happens when there are extra characters inserted prior to the XML declaration, which looks like this  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.   Check the WSDL file and remove any of these characters

Comment: There is nothing like that. Same ear is getting deployed to WAS when I am deploying it through admin console

Comment: I assume you aren't deploying the application from WDT? Do you have a full stack trace or is that all you are seeing? Do you know if the XML file has the unicode BOM character in it? Any chance you could provide the WSDL file?

Comment: I am not deploying using WDT. I am just trying to deploy from inside Eclipse.

Comment: How to Identify if it has BOM character in it? Any suggestion?

Comment: I think if you look in a hex viewer it'll show up as these hex codes in the first 3 bytes: 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF. If you aren't using WDT (or RAD which is based on WDT) how are you deploying from inside Eclipse? Eclipse doesn't come with any support for deploying to WAS.

Comment: I tried using Hex Editor to check the WSDL file.It shows something like below..                                                                                                              3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31.  Also you are right, I am using WDT plugin inside eclipse to publish to WAS